# Adding rows based on the received json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I can enter more then one student details as mentioned in the below  piece of code by clicking the + symbol next to each row and a bin symbol to delete if not required  :

```
<tr class="firstclass" id="school0">
    <td ><input type="text" id="rollnum" name="rollnum" class="rollClass" maxlength="20"/></td>
    <td ><select id="school" name="school" multiple="multiple" style="width: 95px; size: 50px" size="3" class="schoolClass"></td>
    <td><img src="<c:url value="/images/add_small.png"/>" id="btnAdd1" class="addImg"/></td>
    <td><img src="images/delete_small.png" id="btnDelete1" class="delImg"/></td >
</tr>

<tr class="secondclass" id="college0">
    <td ><input type="text" id="rollnum" name="rollnum" class="rollClass" maxlength="20"/></td>
    <td ><select id="college" name="college" multiple="multiple" style="width: 95px; size: 50px" size="3" class="schoolClass"></td>
    <td><img src="<c:url value="/images/add_small.png"/>" id="btnAdd1" class="addImg"/></td>
    <td><img src="images/delete_small.png" id="btnDelete1" class="delImg"/></td >
</tr>
```

But tricky part was how to show them if i had received more then 1 rows of data as a json string .

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: 'get_StudentList',
    async: false,
    data: {
        schrollnum: schrollnum,
        school: school,
        colrollnum: collrollnum,
        college: college
    },
    success: function(response) {
        // No clue if I had received around 10 rows of data 
    }
```

Everything was in jquery

Comment: What is in the json you get?

Comment: {"aaData":[{"schrollnum":"00000386UR","school":"A School"},{"schrollnum":"0023RC","school":"B School"},
{"colrollnum":"00039","college":"A College"},
{"colrollnum":"00049","college":"B college"}]}

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this example and I would suggest you to add a breakpoint inside success call in chrome to check response data or you can use network tab to see the response before you write any code. Code depends on the response JSON structure so check network tab in chrome developer tools to see the response JSON structure.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : "json",
    type : "POST",
    url : 'get_StudentList',
    async : false,
    data : {
    schrollnum: schrollnum,
    school: school,
    colrollnum: collrollnum,
    college: college
    }, 
    success : function(response) {
         //Open your website in chrome and a breakpoint at this line and then you can play with the response data in developer console
         //If your response is in JSON format then you can directly check it like
         if(response.students && response.students.length){
              //Insert elements to DOM from data received
         }
         //If your response is in String format then you will need to parse it
         var studentData = JSON.parse(response);
         if(studentData.students && studentData.students.length){
              //Insert elements to DOM from data received
         }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your response and append rows to the table:

```
success : function(response) {
    var htmlTemplate = '', schoolId;
    response.aaData.forEach( function(item){
         if ( item.schrollnum ){
             schoolId = item.schrollnum;
         } else {
             schoolId = item.colrollnum;
         }             
         htmlTemplate += '<tr class="firstclass" id="' + schoolId + '"><td>...</td></tr>';
    });

    $('#table').append(htmlTemplate);
}
```